Konjugation von "zusammengesetzten" Verben in "um zu" Sätzen
Bei dem Versuch, einen "um zu" Satz mit "zweckentfremden" zu bilden, hat sich mir die Frage gestellt, wie man das eigentlich konjugiert.
Intuitiv, also beim ersten Tippen ohne weiter darüber nachgedacht zu haben, hätte ich die Aussage wie folgt formuliert:

Um mal Lindner zweckzuentfremden: lieber nicht [x], als schlecht [x].

Da bin ich dann allerdings direkt drüber gestolpert, weil mir das dann doch komisch vorkam. Im mündlichen Sprachgebrauch wäre es mir vielleicht nicht weiter aufgefallen, weshalb es sich hier einfach um Umgangssprache handeln und meine Verwirrung daher stammen könnte.
Dabei ist natürlich ohnehin der ganze Satz etwas verkürzt, aber die Formulierung zu "Um einmal Christian Lindners Zitat zur Jamaika-Koalition [...]" zu erweitern, ändert nichts am Problem.
Alternativ habe ich folgende Variante in Betracht gezogen:

Um mal Lindner zu zweckentfremden: [...]

Auch diese Formulierung klingt sehr holprig, wenn nicht sogar mehr als die erste Variante. Wäre das fragliche Verb allerdings "zitieren", hätte ich ohne weiter drüber nachzudenken die zweite Formulierung verwendet:

Um mal Lindner zu zitieren: [...]

Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass meine Verwirrung daher rührt, dass "zweckentfremden" sich leicht in seine ursprünglichen Bestandteile "Zweck" und "entfremden" zerlegen lässt. Wäre es kein "zusammengewachsenes Verb" (den Fachbegriff dafür kenne ich leider nicht), sondern noch in Nomen und Verb getrennt, wäre ich vermutlich nicht darüber gestolpert.
Welche der beiden Varianten ist grammatikalisch denn korrekt? Und gibt es allgemeingültige Regeln für ähnliche Fälle?


Trennbare Verben ziehen bei Infinitivkonstruktionen das "zu" zwischen Vorsilbe und das Stammverb: einzukaufen, umzukehren, mitzulaufen....
"zweckentfremden" ist jedoch kein trennbares Verb (es heißt nicht "ich entfremde Zweck").

Es gibt trotzdem einige wenige nicht-trennbare Verben, die im Infinitiv und Partizip II das gleiche Verhalten wie die Verben in (1) haben - z.B. "notschlachten", "missverstehen",... - eigentlich nicht-trennbare Verben, aber bilden den Infinitiv wie trennbare: "notzuschlachten", "misszuverstehen".


Es wäre also jetzt zu untersuchen, ob "zweckentfremden" zu der Gruppe in (2) gehört:
Die Verben in (2) bilden auch das Partizip analog zu trennbaren Verben, obwohl sie nicht-trennbar sind ("notgeschlachtet"). Das ist bei "zweckentfremden" nicht der Fall - Wahrscheinlich ist also, das dieses Verb nicht zu der Gruppe (2) gehört.
Ganz abgesehen davon hört sich für meine Sprachgebrauch "zweckzuentfremden" sehr, sehr schräg an. Es muss deshalb (auch wenn sich das für mich ebenfalls ein bisschen ungewohnt anhört*) wahrscheinlich richtig(**)

um mal Lindner zu zweckentfremden

heißen.
(*) zweckentfremden ist ein Verb, das fast nur in Partizip- und einfachen Infinitivformen verwendet wird. Das macht jede andere Verwendung ein bißchen auffällig.
(**) Der Online-Duden ist so freundlich, bei Verben der Gruppe (2) (also nicht-trennbaren Verben, die den Infinitiv und das Partizip wie trennbare Verben bilden) den (besonderen) erweiterten Infinitiv in den Beispielen mit anzugeben. Bei "zweckentfremden" tut er das nicht.

"zweckentfremden" in der hier vorliegenden Form ist zwar kein Partizip, aber ein Infinitiv - und der wird durchaus gebraucht. Ohne den Infinitiv kann man nämlich nichts zweckentfremden.

Daß das Partizip Perfekt nicht mit "ge-" gebildet wird, ist nicht nur hier so, sondern bei allen Verben, die mit Präfixen untrennbar verbunden werden. Entfremden ist ein solches Verb, genauso wie zB "erkennen", "verstehen", "bearbeiten", etc..

@bakunin Ich verstehe bei beiden deiner Kommentare leider nicht, was du mir sagen willst.

Ich finde zweckzuentfremden nicht ungewöhnlich und fühle mich durch  Wiktionary bestätigt. Die gleiche Form liefert verbformen.de.

@tofro: Zu der Zeit, als ich den ersten Kommentar schrieb, hat Dein Text das fast nur in Partizipformen gelautet und ich habe das Fehlen der Infinitive (das Du ja mittlerweile nachgetragen hast) bemängelt. Der zweite Kommentar bezog sich darauf, daß das "zu" an dieselbe Stelle wie das "ge" gestellt wird und wenn das "ge" nicht eingeschoben wird, dann auch nicht das "zu".

Achso. Das zweite ist ja eben der Punkt, um den es geht.....
